# Get Data by Given Index

Tags: java, arrays

While coding a program for employee-management, I need a method which spits out the corresponding data to a specific index (the number given by the user).
Already tried a lot of methods to make this happen, for example the one below, with no success:

```java
public static void ausgabeIndex(int index, String[] nN, String[] vN, String[] adres) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please insert the number of the registered employees: ");
    index = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {
        if (nN[i].equals(index)) {
            System.out.println(nN[index]);
            System.out.println(vN[index]);
            System.out.println(adres[index]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think this does? `nN[i].equals(index)`. This is asking if a String `nN[i]` is equal to an `int`.

Comment: Yes, I actually know that its function is comparing tow strings. I tried everything possible, my first try was this: `nN[I] == index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear if there is more than one issue here, since you didn't say what the actual problem was, other than it doesn't work.

Also, your data here is a bit strange. This would be better suited as a `class` to encapsulate all the data instead of three string arrays.

I suspect, however, that this is part of your problem: `nN[i].equals(index)`

`nN` is an array of `String`, and `index` is an `int`. These will *never* be equal. They aren't the same data type.

To properly compare a String and an integer, you need to either convert the `String` to an `int` or the `int` to a `String`. Converting an `int` to a String is the safer option, so you could do this:

`nN[i].equals(String.valueOf(index))`

To do the opposite, converting a `String` to an `int`, you can use `Integer.parseInt(String)`

`Integer.parseInt(nN[i]) == index`

One more note:
`public static void ausgabeIndex(int index`

You are passing in `index` but immediately overwriting it with your `Scanner.nextInt`. You don't need it as a method argument.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for your reply. The only issue here, is java not accepting it(my input for index, to search for the data that correspond). I tried yet one more time with your recommendations. Unfortunately no success: 

`for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++)
            if (nN[i].equals(String.valueOf(index))) {
                System.out.println("Der Nachname des/der Mitarbeiters/Mitarbeiterin ist: " + nN[i]);
            } `

Comment: That code will function exactly as it should. There's something else wrong, so you may want to use a debugger to step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the following things in your code:

1. Whenver you try to access an element from an array, make sure you check the bounds to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` e.g. you have accessed `vN[index]` without checking whether `index` is less than `vN.length`. `adres[index]` also has the same problem.
2. `nN[i]` is a `String` while `i` is an `int` and therefore they can not be compared unless you change the one into the other. However, I'm sure you didn't mean to compare `nN[i]` with `index`. Looking at your program, it seems you want to compare `nN[i]` with `nN[index]`.
3. Since you are already passing `index` as a parameter to the method, the following lines do not make sense unless you want to override the value of `index`. If you do not want to override the value of parameter, `index`, remove these lines.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Geben Sie bitte die Nummer des/der regestrierten Mitarbeiters/Mitarbeiterin ein: ");
index = sc.nextInt();
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep these lines in the method, remove the parameter, `index`. As I've mentioned above, keeping both of these makes sense only if you want to override the value of parameter, `index`.

Given below is the code incorporating these comments:

```
 public static void ausgabeIndex(int index, String[] nN, String[] vN, String[] adres) {
    if(index < nN.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {
            if (nN[i].equals(nN[index])) {
                System.out.println(nN[index]);
                if (index < vN.length) {
                    System.out.println(vN[index]);
                }
                if (index < adres.length) {
                    System.out.println(adres[index]);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printnl("The index, " + index + " is out of the bounds.");
    }
}
```